# gpssh-exkeys -f hostfile_exkeys ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512

Tags: greenplum

i try to install greenplum database and in this [step](http://docs.greenplum.org/6-8/install_guide/install_gpdb.html#topic10)
got error. my looks like
host1 host2 host3. what i'm doing wrong?

```
$ gpssh-exkeys -f hostfile_exkeys
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.12.1/ext/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/greenplum-db-6.12.1/ext/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Error: unable to import module: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed by `yum install compat-openssl10`